# How to create a matrix of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a matrix MxN where every element of the matrix is a list of integers. I need a list so that I can append new elements as I go, therefore a 3D matrix would not work here.
I'm not sure if what I need here would actually be a list of lists.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `numpy`?

Comment: What is the purpose of this lists? Why you think a 3D array won't work?

Comment: The reason why I think a 3D array would not work is because I have to dynamically append elements to a given position (M,N) in the program. I have taken a look at numpy, but I'm not sure what to do for a matrix of lists

Comment: You can dynamically append elements to any `list`, so using a "3D" list-of-lists-of-lists ought to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function creates a 2D matrix of empty lists:

```
>>> def create(row,col):
...     return [[[] for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)]
...
>>> L = create(2,3)
>>> L[1][2].extend([1,2,3]) # add multiple integers at a location
>>> for row in L:
...   print(row)
...
[[], [], []]
[[], [], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> L[0][1].append(1) # add one more integer at a location
>>> for row in L:
...   print(row)
...
[[], [1], []]
[[], [], [1, 2, 3]]
```

How it works:

- `[]` is a new instance of an empty list.
- `[[] for _ in range(col)]` uses a list comprehension to create a list of "col" empty lists.
- `[[] for _ in range(col)] for _ in range(row)` create "row" new lists of "col" empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, you can create a matrix with dtype=object (instead of the usual int or float). This can be used to store empty lists, to which you can then append.